# SQL Wordpress Query - inner vs outer join

Tags: mysql, wordpress, outer-join

I'm trying to get all posts where the wp_postmeta table has `(meta_key='propdetails' AND meta_value LIKE '%Vacant Unrented Ready%')`, or `(meta_key='featured' AND meta_value='on')`.

My existing query (below) is working, except when the meta_key 'featured' row is *missing*. Then, that post is not returned.

Similarly, for matching rows, I also need to retrieve I want to get the `meta_value` where `meta_key='martygeocoderlatlng'`. However, if that meta_key is missing, then that entire post isn't returned at all.

So I need to take my existing query and make `meta_key='featured'` or `meta_key='martygeocoderlatlng'` optional, so if they aren't there, I still can do my other comparisons and get the data I need.

(I think this would be done with an OUTER JOIN somehow, but I can't quite sort out the syntax.)

Here's my existing query, which returns only rows where meta_key='featured' and meta_key='martygeocoderlatlng' exist in the wp_postmeta table (and the other conditions in the WHERE clause are met, of course):

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    pm.*,
    pm_featured.meta_value AS featured,
    pm_latlng.meta_value AS latlng

FROM 
    wp_posts p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm
      ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_propdetails
      ON (pm_propdetails.post_id = p.ID AND pm_propdetails.meta_key = 'propdetails')
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_featured
      ON (pm_featured.post_id = p.ID AND pm_featured.meta_key = 'featured-property')
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_latlng
      ON (pm_latlng.post_id = p.ID AND pm_latlng.meta_key = 'martygeocoderlatlng')

    JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
      ON tr.object_id = p.ID
    JOIN wp_term_relationships tr_taxrel
      ON (tr_taxrel.object_id = p.ID AND tr_taxrel.term_taxonomy_id = 12)

WHERE
    (pm_propdetails.meta_value LIKE '%Vacant Unrented Ready%'
        OR
     pm_featured.meta_value = 'on')

    AND p.post_type = 'property'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'

GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty intense query. It's hard to know exactly how to do this efficiently without knowing your table structures better (seems like a few of those JOINS could be combined).

Here is a stab just by editing your original query:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    pm.*,
    pm_featured.meta_value AS featured,
    pm_latlng.meta_value AS latlng

FROM 
    wp_posts p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm
      ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_propdetails
      ON (pm_propdetails.post_id = p.ID AND pm_propdetails.meta_key = 'propdetails')
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm_featured
      ON (pm_featured.post_id = p.ID AND pm_featured.meta_key = 'featured-property')
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm_latlng
      ON (pm_latlng.post_id = p.ID AND pm_latlng.meta_key = 'martygeocoderlatlng')

    JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
      ON tr.object_id = p.ID
    JOIN wp_term_relationships tr_taxrel
      ON (tr_taxrel.object_id = p.ID AND tr_taxrel.term_taxonomy_id = 12)

WHERE
    (pm_propdetails.meta_value LIKE '%Vacant Unrented Ready%'
        OR
     (pm_featured.meta_value = 'on' OR pm_feature.meta_value IS NULL))

    AND p.post_type = 'property'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'

GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

It's just using LEFT JOINs to try to return the posts where meta_key might be missing, and then the WHERE section was modified to try to account for if pm_featured.meta_value IS NULL.

Could try another version if you provide some more info.

Edit:
According to your question, this might also work. Really just a huge shot in the dark though =)

```
SELECT T2.*, T1.featured, T1.latlng FROM
(
    SELECT post_id, SUM(IF((meta_key='propdetails' AND meta_value LIKE '%Vacant Unrented Ready%') OR ((meta_key='featured' AND meta_value='on')),1,0)) AS Keeper
    , MAX(IF(meta_key = 'featured-property',meta_value,NULL)) AS featured
    , MAX(IF(meta_key = 'martygeocoderlatlng',meta_value,NULL)) AS latlng
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    GROUP BY post_id
    HAVING Keeper>0
) AS T1
JOIN
wp_posts AS T2
ON T1.post_id=T2.ID
AND T2.post_type = 'property'
AND T2.post_status = 'publish'
JOIN
wp_term_relationships AS T3
ON T2.ID=T3.object_id AND T3.term_taxonomy_id = 12
GROUP BY T2.ID
ORDER BY T2.post_date DESC
```

Since the second query ended up working (A little surprising, I made a lot of assumptions ;) this one *should* be slightly faster and a little easier to understand...
(Note: especially if you have a composite index on (`meta_key`,`meta_value`) in the `wp_postmeta` table.)

```
SELECT T2.*, T1.featured, T1.latlng FROM
(
    SELECT postmetas_info.post_id
    , MAX(IF(meta_key = 'featured-property',meta_value,NULL)) AS featured
    , MAX(IF(meta_key = 'martygeocoderlatlng',meta_value,NULL)) AS latlng
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key='propdetails' AND meta_value LIKE '%Vacant Unrented Ready%') OR (meta_key='featured' AND meta_value='on')
    ) AS postmetas_applicable
    JOIN
    wp_postmeta AS postmetas_info
    ON postmetas_applicable.post_id=postmetas_info.post_id
    GROUP BY postmetas_info.post_id
) AS T1
JOIN
wp_posts AS T2
ON T1.post_id=T2.ID
AND T2.post_type = 'property'
AND T2.post_status = 'publish'
JOIN
wp_term_relationships AS T3
ON T2.ID=T3.object_id AND T3.term_taxonomy_id = 12
GROUP BY T2.ID
ORDER BY T2.post_date DESC
```

The SUM(IF()) in the previous query is kind of fun but probably not as performant as it could be since it evaluates every row in the table. The query above whittles down the post_id's first and then just grabs the corresponding data based on only eligible post_id's after that.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for this great response. I'm playing with your queries now... the 2nd one seems to be working better than the 1st one, oddly. Some clever stuff you have going on there!

Comment: Haha, yeah that one was kind of fun to write. Could probably be a bit more efficient though. Anything it's not doing that you still need it to do?

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly. Really appreciate your help! Now I just need to set aside a few minutes to really disassemble this statement and really understand what all you did here. I love the 'sum' trick.